# How to test legacy code that uses a logger which requires initialization?

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging

I am writing **unit tests** for legacy code that uses a logger similar to this:

```
public class MyLogger {
    private static Logger logger;

    public static void init() throws SomeException {
        //initialize the logger field
    }

    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }
}
```

The logger requires initialization, otherwise it returns null, and **the tests fail** because of a `NullPointerException` coming from the code under test that uses the logger.

**My goal is to test the legacy code without depending on the logger at all (initialized or not) when i test.**

Possible solutions:

1. Add a call to `MyLogger.init()` in the test - bad solution because of many reasons.
2. Initialize the logger in `getLogger` if it hasn't been initialized - i don't like this solution because then `getLogger` has to deal with 'SomeException'.
3. Initialize the logger with a "NullLogger" that does nothing.

I chose solution #3, but that requires me to inherit from Logger, which has about 60 functions, and call its constructor, and carefully check which methods of the logger are called from my code, so i can choose a proper "null" implementation.

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: Could you explain many reasons against option one ?

Comment: Why is 1 a bad solution? It is how your code works. This is the way you should test it.

Comment: @user3360241
The goal is to test code that is **using** the MyLogger class.
I don't like option #1 because:
1) When i write a test for class X (that uses MyLogger), i am interested in testing the behavior of class X. I am not interested in testing that class X is calling the MyLogger class in most tests.
2) Initializing the logger slows down my tests, because it creates a log file.
Moreover, when the class under tests writes to the log, it writes to the file system and that is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mocking framework to create a `NullLogger`. You could use "Mockito" or "PowerMock" or "EasyMock" or any other framework.

**Mocked** objects are automatically generated subclasses, whose behaviour can be defined programmatically. By default functions of mocked objects will do nothing and return null (for non void methods).

You might want to change the logger field to package privacy, to be able to set it from inside your test without having to use reflection.

Example code using Mockito 1.9.5:

```
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

class SomeException extends Exception {

}

class MyLogger
{
    static Logger logger; // changed to package privacy
    public static void init() throws SomeException {
        //initialize the logger field
    }
    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }
}

public class MyLoggerTest {

    @Test
    public void someTest() {

        // set "NullLogger"
        MyLogger.logger = Mockito.mock(Logger.class);

        // access to logger won't fail anymore
        MyLogger.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "uninteresting stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @slartidan.
I actually want to test code that uses the MyLogger class, not the class itself.

Comment: @e.t. Testing other code should also work with this approach.

Comment: Almost all classes in the code base are using the logger.
I am not sure it is good practice that almost all the unit tests will need to mock the logger. I would prefer that the logger be initialized by default by a mock, until initialized, but i am not sure that using a mocking framework as part of the production code is a good idea, that is why i manually mocked the logger.